# What does '所至‘ mean?

Tags: meaning

What's the best way to think of the phrase in English?   It seems to be a very formal sort of expression.

For example, "多数是工作时数超长疲劳所至."

Thanks,
Rachel

(Edit:  Thank you.  I didn't realize it was a typo for a different phrase.)

Comment: "attributable,due to,resulting from", here:
 "most have been attributed to fatigue due to long working hours", cf. iciba: 相关例句： 1.
    Many of these incidences have been attributed to fatigue due to long working hours.
在这些安全事件中,多数是工作时数超长疲劳所至, 
find over 100 example sentences in jukuu (often used in headlines)

Comment: comment #1, of course applies to  所致,（much more common than 所至）,  jukuu still has over １００ example sentences for 所致

Answer (score 12):

As @user6065 has pointed out, we can find the example sentence in many online dictionaries:

> 在这些安全事件中，多数是工作时数超长疲劳[**所至**］。( **Typo Warning!** )
> Many of these incidences have been attributed to fatigue due to long working hours.

**However, in that sentence, the only correct word should be 所致**, i.e. it should have been

> 在这些安全事件中，多数是工作时数超长疲劳**所致**。( **Correct!** )

**所致** can be considered as a short form for "所导致", so it means **"be caused by"**, **"be the result of"**. It is sharply distinguished from **所至**, whose 至 means 到达 (reach, arrive at). 所至 is not commonly used, except in this idiom:

> 精诚所至，金石为开
>
> Literally this idiom means "At the place where the true faith reaches, even rigid stone can be cracked." That is to say, **"Faith can move mountains."**